# How to change format of a dict in Python?

Tags: python, function

I have a dictionary or list as below.

```
dictt ={'X , 5,5,8,7,7,6', 'Y , 2,1,2,3,2', 'Z , 3,3,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,4'}
```

How can I convert it below format as list or dictionary? I want to see each X/Y/Z for their unique values. I should not use pandas or numpy.

```
X 5
X 8
X 7 
X 6
Y 2
Y 1
Y 3
Z 3
Z 4
Z 5
```

The original data format:

```
['endDate,weight',
 ' 2020-06-12  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.5,91.9,91.9,91.9,92.55,92.55,92.55,92.55,92.1,92.1,93.3,93.3 ',
 ' 2020-06-13  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.6,91.6,92.85,92.85,92.85,92.85,92.3,92.3,92.1,92.1,94.1,94.1 ',
 ' 2020-06-14  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.5,91.5,91.65,91.65,91.5,91.5,92.9,92.9 ',
 ' 2020-06-15  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.85,91.85,91.6,91.6,91.85,91.85,92.55,92.55,92.4,92.4,93.7,93.7,93.35,93.35 ',
 ' 2020-06-16  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.6,91.6,91.3,91.3,92.75,92.75,92.15,92.15,93.15,93.15,92.9,92.9 ',
 ' 2020-06-17  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.05,91.05,91.85,91.85,92.4,92.4,92.4,92.4,94.0,94.0,93.7,93.7,93.05,93.05,93.05,93.05 ',
 ' 2020-06-18  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.55,91.55,91.45,91.45,91.25,91.25,91.65,92.2,91.95 ',
 ' 2020-06-19  00:00:00+03:00 , 91.3,91.6,92.45,92.05,91.8,93.1,92.7,93.5,93.15 ',
 ' 2020-06-20  00:00:00+03:00 , 90.8,90.8,90.6,90.6,90.6,90.6,92.15,92.15,92.05,92.05,91.4,91.4 ']
```

Comment: Your input is neither a list nor a dictionary. Typically is a set. You want something like {'x' : [5,8,7,6], 'y': [2,1,3] ...} etc?

Comment: `dictt` is a `set` are you sure that is what you have?

Comment: My data is little bit complex than this. Actually, I will use counter for them. But in this version  I cannot apply. If I can see X/Y/Z values as count of their unique values,I can apply it.  I need to like this: {'x' : 5, 'x' : 8, 'x' : 7, 'x' : 6, 'y' :  2, 'y' : 3, ...}

Comment: @user14800447 Is your "more complex" data, the same as your [earlier question today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65274300/parsing-text-file-in-python-into-a-dictionary)? If so, Add the actual data to the question, as text, not as a picture.

Comment: Dictionaries only allow one value per key, so what you wan't isn't possible by means of a dictionary. How about @IoaTzimas suggestion?

Comment: I added the original data.

Answer (score 1):

For the specific input that you provided, which is a set (not a list or dictionary):

```
dictt ={'X , 5,5,8,7,7,6', 'Y , 2,1,2,3,2', 'Z , 3,3,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,4'}
```

You can get a dictionary wiht the following:

```
res={i.split(',')[0].strip() : [int(k.strip()) for k in i.split(',')[1:]] for i in dictt}
```

which gives the following:

```
>>> print(res)

{'X': [5, 5, 8, 7, 7, 6], 'Z': [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4], 'Y': [2, 1, 2, 3, 2]}
```

If you now want to print each key with its values separately as you described, you can do it with the following:

```
for i in res:
    for k in set(res[i]):
        print(i, k)

X 8
X 5
X 6
X 7
Z 3
Z 4
Z 5
Y 1
Y 2
Y 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data struct is a dict (**not** the one you have provided) - here is the code. (If it is not a dict - please update the question with the actual data struct)

```
data = {'X': '5,5,8,7,7,6', 'Y': '2,1,2,3,2', 'Z': '3,3,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,4'}
for k, v in data.items():
    temp = set(v.split(','))
    for x in temp:
        print(f'{k} {x}')
```

output

```
X 5
X 6
X 7
X 8
Y 2
Y 1
Y 3
Z 5
Z 4
Z 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_dict = {}
for i in dictt:
    key, value = i.split(' , ')
    value = (int(num) for num in value.split(','))
    value = set(value)
    new_dict[key] = value
```

This will return a dictionary of the form `{'X': {5, 8, 7, 6}, 'Y': {2, 1, 3}, 'Z': {3, 4, 5}}`. This is probably not the exact dictionary you're looking for but the question isn't very clear as to what is required and dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys (`{'X': 5, 'X': 8}` is not possible).

Answer (score 0):

```py
dictt = {"X , 5,5,8,7,7,6", "Y , 2,1,2,3,2", "Z , 3,3,3,4,4,5,4,5,5,4"}

l = [[e.strip() for e in splitted] for splitted in [x.split(",") for x in list(dictt)]]

# Removing duplicates by turning them into set and list again
d = {x[0]: list(set(x[1:])) for x in l}

for k, values in d.items():
    for v in values:
        print(f"{k} {v}")
```

Which outputs:

```
X 6
X 5
X 8
X 7
Y 2
Y 3
Y 1
Z 3
Z 4
Z 5
```